# UITableView reload and move rows in same batch update results in 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

Here's a simple example (basically made from "Master-Detail" Xcode template).

I'm trying to move one row ("B") and reload another row ("A1" -> "A2") in a batch update in UITableView.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.objects = @[@"B", @"A1"];
}

- (IBAction)boom
{
    self.objects = @[@"A2", @"B"];

    NSIndexPath *path0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path0 toIndexPath:path1];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

This results in the following exception:

```
2015-01-14 17:58:51.290 batchtest[34004:806671] *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableViewSupport.m:1216
2015-01-14 17:58:51.335 batchtest[34004:806671] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00946946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005cfa97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x009467da +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x00243810 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x010b18e5 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForNewlyInsertedCells] + 8447
    5   UIKit                               0x010bb422 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 207
    6   UIKit                               0x00df8bc1 -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2089
    7   UIKit                               0x00df24a8 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 13867
    8   UIKit                               0x00e07b6f -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 51
    9   UIKit                               0x00e07b9d -[UITableView endUpdates] + 41
```

Same thing happens when I try to pass `@[path0]` to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` instead of `@[path1]`.

This looks like an iOS bug to me. Is there a way around it? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is an answer from the Apple engineering about this issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9642438/2128900. Seems that you have to use an ugly workaround: "just reach into the cell and change the contents".

Comment: Thanks, Michał. The issue there is about reloading the same row that is being moved (which also makes sense, btw). I'm trying to reload *another* cell. Anyway, I'll think about some generic way to update cells directly instead of calling "reload" (obviously what I'm really doing is not precisely this sample with two cells).

Comment: please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372884/uitableview-using-moverowatindexpathtoindexpath-and-reloadrowsatindexpathswi

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, there is nothing wrong with this exception. The `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` creates an animation for a row being reloaded, and `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` also creates an animation. Obviously, UITableView can't handle 2 simultaneous animations and throws an exception.

I guess that passing the `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` to the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` could solve the problem but not sure; still, worth to try.

I'd propose a workaround like this:

```
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path0 toIndexPath:path1];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.objects = @[@"A2", @"B"];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path1]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
});
```

or this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    self.objects = @[@"A2", @"B"];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path1]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path0 toIndexPath:path1];
[CATransaction commit];
```

or this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path0 toIndexPath:path1];
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    self.objects = @[@"A2", @"B"];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path1]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}];
```

Comment: UITableView can handle multiple animations in a batch update—that's what batch updates are for. What it complaints about is that a single *cell* has two animations. But in my opinion reload animation goes to the [initially] second cell and move animation goes to [initially] first cell.

Comment: I guess all animations are created simultaneously, so you get several simultaneous animations for `path1`

Comment: UITableViewRowAnimationNone does not help. Also I don't want to introduce any asynchronousness since it will break if another update occurs in between. However, doing to "move" first, and "reload" later in a separate batch synchronously, does help. But I don't see any reason behind this, especially since "reload, then move" does not work properly.

Comment: `path1` in "move" is where the "B" cell will move to, it's not the same *cell* as the one that's *initially* at `path1`.

Comment: I don't think that CATransaction does anything different from dispatch_async, like it doesn't wait on the previous animation to end or anything because it isn't created there, its created in endUpdates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, just by canceling `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`. 
By the way, iOS 8.4 and 9.x solved the problem, however, iOS 8.1 is NOT OK.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dawn Song said: in iOS 8.4 up, this problem is not happen, but only  8.1 down I guess(not yet tested with 8.0 and down)

In iOS8.1, maybe u shall update cell one by one. This work for me: 
Your code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path0 toIndexPath:path1];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Try change to this:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:path0 toIndexPath:path1];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

But note that: Your `path1` should have only 1 NSIndexPath